# Portability of VTK applications

Tags: linux, qt, portability, vtk, qvtkwidget

My program was written with some vtk and qvtkwidget stuffs. I want to know is the portability going to be an issue? Can someone run the program on his own computer without vtk installed on it? UPDATE: I am using Linux as operative system, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've created an application for Windows: **yes**, you just need to include the .dll files with your exe. Since you are using VTK and "qvtkwidget stuffs" (I presume Qt...), you have to include the .dll files of VTK and Qt that you use in your application.

Now, if you try to run your application on another PC, with no VTK/Qt libraries in its file system, you'll almost certainly receive an error, something like "*The program can't start because xx.dll is missing from your computer [...]*".

[image]

So, you just need to include all the necessary .dll files until the application will work fine. At that point, you'll be sure that the application is portable between all Windows machines (assuming a Windows version that is compatible with your distribution of Qt and VTK, of course).

Comment: I am using linux. What if my program has no .so files? It will just produce a single executable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no experience about VTK on Linux. Technically, your program should be portable as well, but I don't take the risk in giving you wrong infos. I edited your question with the correct tags - and specifing that you're using Linux -, hoping that it'll get more visibility.